# Elastic Beanstalk Deploy ERROR: AttributeError :: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I try to deploy to my Elastic Beanstalk environment I am getting this python error. Everything was working fine a few days ago.

```
$ eb deploy
ERROR: AttributeError :: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I've thus far attempted to update everything to no effect by issuing the following commands:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

and

```
sudo pip install --upgrade awscli
```

Here are the resulting versions I'm working with:

```
$ eb --version
EB CLI 3.10.0 (Python 2.7.1)

$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.56 Python/2.7.13rc1 Darwin/16.4.0 botocore/1.5.19
```

Everything looks fine under eb status

```
$ eb status
Environment details for: ***
  Application name: ***
  Region: us-west-2
  Deployed Version: ***
  Environment ID: ***
  Platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v3.3.1 running Node.js
  Tier: WebServer-Standard
  CNAME: ***.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2017-03-02 14:48:29.099000+00:00
  Status: Ready
  Health: Green
```

This issue appears to only effect this elastic beanstalk project. I am able to deploy to another project on the same AWS account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue. Turns out that when you enable CodeCommit the CLI looks for a remote called "codecommit-origin" and if you don't have a git remote with that *specific* name it will throw that error.

Posting this for anyone else who stumbles upon the same issue.

Comment: I stopped using the CodeCommit. What's the solution to fix this? I couldn't find anything in the config file that mentions codecommit

Comment: Found a fix. I had to delete the CodeCommit repository completely to prevent this (even tho there was no mention of codecommit in my `/.elasticbeanstalk/config.yaml`

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this with `eb codesource local && eb deploy`, so it forgets about CodeCommit.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error I needed to add the following lines to my `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml`

`branch-defaults:
 master:
   environment: prod-api 
   group_suffix: null
 staging:
   environment: staging-api
   group_suffix: null`

You'll need to change the branch names and environments to what is applicable to your case (in our case we have a master branch deploying to an eb environment named prod-api).